# 2N3904 Darlington Pair

Tags: amplifier, darlington

I am making a amplifier with darlington Pair with 2N3904. In input i used my mobile phone & additional supply of 5 volt. It simulates well in Multisim11 BUT in real the second transistor gets so hot. When i open the power supply mobile shows audio connected but when the power supply connected it lost connection from mobile from but i can hear sound in my amplifires speaker as well as my mobile phones speaker. 
*** Second transistor gets so hot....!!!
[image]

Comment: Show us your circuit. Note that the 2N3904 is a small-signal transistor, no a power transistor.

Comment: As Wouter says, we need to see your schematic - you are new so you can't add pictures yet, but if you put it somewhere and link to it we'll add it into your question for you. It's likely you are exceeding the current specs for the second 2N3904, or similar.

Comment: My reputation is under 10 so i cant post images. I am giving external link for my circuit. The Link: http://wp.me/a1SxVN-8Q

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You are trying to drive a speaker and also feed DC through the 2nd transistor - it's no-surprise the 2nd transistor gets warm - it sees a dc load that is a few ohms (the speaker) and will get hot.

2) The dc current through the 2nd transistor also passes through the speaker and this could damage the speaker. Speakers expect an ac current (as from a normal amplifier). The dc current will offset the position of the cone/diaphram and likely damage it. Sound quality and loudness will also be significantly impaired.

3) Your input signal will not take the biasing voltage you have tried to apply. The voltage source in the diagram will shunt the attempt at applied dc bias to ground - in effect, any sounds produced will be from the upper positive peaks of the signal applied.

Solutions to (1)&(2) you would do better with a push-pull amplifier set-up with a capacitor feeding the speaker from the emitters of a standard pair of NPN and PNP transistors OR use an LM386 chip. I wouldn't bother trying to solve (3) because solutions to (1)&(2) negate solving it BUT putting a capacitor in series with the voltage generator will allow you to see what I mean in the simulator.